# Add html code in admin page

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm trying to add floating button in admin page.

If I using

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_admin_function');
```

The button will in the bottom of the page and I need to scroll down.

I need the button always on the bottom of the screen and I don't have to scroll down.

Is there have action API that can add  some code in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing little CSS work

```
.admin-button{position:fixed; bottom:20px; right:20px; z-index:999;}
```

add class to your button code, here I am using ".admin-button" for example .This will make your button appear in bottom 20px up and 20px away from right , more do as wherever you want to place.

Hope this small thing can work for you